# executing multiple greps in a single find command

Tags: bash, grep, find

I want to use find command to find some files containing multiple patterns at the same time.

I tried something like this:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -iH keyword1 + && grep -iH "keyword2" {} \;
```

But the above command doesn't work.

Is it possible to do it in bash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand, you want to list files that contain **both** "keyword1" and "keyword2". To do that, you can use two `-exec` tests in following way:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -iq keyword1 {} \; -exec grep -iH keyword2 {} \;
```

This will run the second `grep` conditionally - if the first one returned true. The `-q` option prevents output from the first `grep`, as it would list all the files that include only "keyword1".

Since the `-H` option outputs the matching line together with the file name, you'd probably want to use `-l` instead. So

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -iq keyword1 {} \; -exec grep -il keyword2 {} \;
```

This will yield similar output to what Caleb suggested, but without the need of additional `-print`.

Comment: Does this mean that `find` will always exit immediately when an `-exec` returns a non-zero value?

Comment: Not exactly "exit". `-exec` is really *a test* that `find` performs on the file - and all the tests are by default chained using an *and* logic - see `man find` :)

Answer (score 6):

First, to do this with find you would add a second `-exec` argument. Each argument is only able to run one command. If you needed to run multiple things you would have to use a hack by making the one command a shell and running multiple commands. Here it is with `find` doing the work:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -qi "keyword1" {} \; -exec grep -qi "keyword2" {} \; -print
```

Note that I have used finds `-print` option to output the files names instead of having grep do it and used the `-q` option of grep to put it in silent mode so that it simply gives a return code that can be used by find to tell if the result was true or not, then move on. If it reaches the last step (meaning both files have matched) it prints the output.

However this is inefficient because grep is actually having to scan all the files twice. If you meant your question literally this will have to do, but if you meant to find files containing ANY of the strings you can use grep to search for both patterns on one pass like this:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -qi -e "keyword1" -e "keyword2" {} \; -print
```

**Edit:** It is unclear in your question what exactly you want to have happen, and the two examples I gave actually do different things. The first one is an AND operation and only prints files that contain both keywords and the second is an OR operation that prints the file name if it contains either string. Pick your poison.

Comment: I understand the question differently - you give a recipe for **or** logic, but the OP has **&&** in his line, so he probably wants to find files that contain **both** keywords.

Comment: Ah, I see you already corrected it. :)

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Your comment came in about 4 minutes after I fixed that oversight in my answer (probably while you were working up something similar in yours).

Comment: Probably :) And OldTimer's comment to my comment came even later :D

Comment: It would be handy if the OP would come back and clarify. Since to me it now seems he wants to see all of the lines in the file that contain both words, not just the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use egrep:

`find . -name "*.xml" -exec egrep -iH "keyword1|keyword2" {} \;`

Comment: This accomplishes a different search - you have **or**, the OP asked for **and**.

Comment: If so, it seems none of us have the right answer at this time then.

Comment: I think it was indeed so. But I see Caleb has just modified his answer according to that interpretation.

Comment: I was trying to answer this myself with only regex, and I found a [similar question on Unix.com](http://www.unix.com/90215-post13.html), with an answer of `word1.*word2|word2.*word1`